# Seeking solution to maintain stable codeline in Git using feature branches

Tags: git, branch

Seeking a solution to this problem.

We work with Git on one large feature branch off develop branch. Team prefers this way claiming individual feature branches would limit developers working similar issues and who need to share code changes.

At end of sprint, feature\integration branch is merged to develop branch (the Configuration managed controlled branch).

My problem is develop branch always contains some half-baked code each release.  Some issues can't finish during sprint, yet changes were committed; and yet those that are finished may depend on the half-baked code to build successfully. Is it even possible to keep a stable, tested, peer-reviewed main codeline?

Comment: If you have one large feature branch, that's just a second develop branch. It's not a feature branch anymore at that point.

Comment: yeh, that's true, didn't think of it that way. Thanks Pockets

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your develop branch should only contain features that are fully develop

> At any point of time, develop branch  should be ready for production.

Now coming to the point of that some changes depend on another. If that is the case then there should be a separate feature branch for that common piece of functionality. which should be develop and tested and merged to develop before some one else starts another feature work which needs this common piece.

You should slice your features as small as possible instead of creating an umbrella feature which has a lot of small features. An umbrella branch becomes hard to test,also  it will be long lived since you will need more time to finish the feature that will create more merge issues,(as more things have merged to develop by now).

My rule of thumb is

1. Create small features which can be tested and merged quickly.
2. A long lived branch in a BIG NO.
3. Prioritize your sprint in a way that features which depend on each other are not taken in the same sprint.

I think it is more of an art then exact science.

Comment: Thank you very much root545. This is very helpful advice.